# I want to read two files in Java, one .xlsx and one .csv, and want to display the contents on the console based on the extension of the file

Tags: java, excel, apache, csv

I want to read two files in Java, one `.xlsx` and one `.csv`, and want to display the contents on the console based on the extension of the file. I've stored the extension in `ext1` and `ext2`, but I'm not getting how do I display the contents of the file based on the extension.

```
package com.pack;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

public class TP {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        try {
            String ext1 = FilenameUtils.getExtension("C:\\Users\\swapnil.sanjay.saraf\\Desktop\\Input.xlsx"); // returns "txt"
            String ext2 = FilenameUtils.getExtension("C:\\Users\\swapnil.sanjay.saraf\\Desktop\\Input2.csv"); // returns "exe"
            String input = null;
            String excelPath = "C:\\Users\\swapnil.sanjay.saraf\\Desktop\\Input.xlsx";
            if (excelPath == ext1)

            {

                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelPath));

                // Create Workbook instance holding .xls file
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);

                // Get the first worksheet
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

                // Iterate through each rows
                Iterator < Row > rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
                System.out.println("\n******XLSX FILE******\n");
                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                    // Get Each Row
                    Row row = rowIterator.next();

                    // Iterating through Each column of Each Row
                    Iterator < Cell > cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                        // Checking the cell format
                        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
                System.out.println(ext1);
            }
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is comparing ext1, which should contain only the extension "xlsx", to excelPath, which contains the full file path "C:\\Users\\swapnil.sanjay.saraf\\Desktop\\Input.xlsx".  Perhaps you meant to compare ext1 with "xlsx" instead?

Comment: @PhilGrigsby yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this approach. Please compare the String with equals function. "==" represents address only.

```
public class TP
{
public static final String extXlsx="xlsx";
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    try
    {

        String ext1 = FilenameUtils.getExtension("C:\\Users\\swapnil.sanjay.saraf\\Desktop\\Input.xlsx"); // returns "txt"
        String ext2 = FilenameUtils.getExtension("C:\\Users\\swapnil.sanjay.saraf\\Desktop\\Input2.csv"); // returns "exe"
        String input = null;
        String excelPath = "C:\\Users\\swapnil.sanjay.saraf\\Desktop\\Input.xlsx";
        System.out.println(FilenameUtils.getExtension(excelPath));
        if(ext1.equals(FilenameUtils.getExtension(excelPath))){

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelPath));

            // Create Workbook instance holding .xls file
            //Excel Handling
        } else{
            System.out.println("\n******CSV FILE******\n");
            //CSV File handling
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ie){
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Why are you comparing extension with string ext1, ext2. Better you can compare file extension with static values as you need

```
public static final String extXlsx="xlsx";
public static final String extXls="xls";
// Put the above two strings above Public static void main()

if(extXlsx.equals(FilenameUtils.getExtension(excelPath))||
 extXls.equals(FilenameUtils.getExtension(excelPath))){
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelPath));
        // Create Workbook instance holding .xls file
        //Excel Handling
    } else{
        System.out.println("\n******CSV FILE******\n");
        //CSV File handling
    }
```

I think this is your objective. If not please comment.

Comment: its throwing error "Invalid modifier" on public static final String extXlsx="xlsx";
public static final String extXls="xls";

Comment: I have edited the post. Please check now. Put those two strings above public static void main.